# How to defalias lambda?

Tags: elisp

I have this in my .emacs:

```
(defalias 'λ 'lambda)
```

which works fine for simple things like `(funcall (λ (x) x) 1)`.

But when I do something like `(org-add-link-type "foo" (λ (s) (message s)))` or `(add-to-list 'auto-mode-alist '("foo" . (λ () (message "bar"))))`, it doesn't work and I get

> org-open-at-point: Invalid function: (λ (s) (message s))

and

> File mode specification error: (invalid-function (λ nil (message "bar")))

respectively.

Does anybody know what's wrong here?

Comment: Not an answer to the question about the `defalias`, but you might want to check out [`prettify-symbols-mode`](http://ergoemacs.org/emacs/emacs_pretty_lambda.html), which, among other things, will allow you to display `lambda` as `λ` without actually changing the underlying text.

Comment: A simple library that prettifies *only* `lambda` (to `λ`): [`pretty-lambdada.el`](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs-en/download/pretty-lambdada.el).

Comment: If you just want pretty symbols then use https://github.com/akatov/pretty-mode

Answer (score 12, accepted):

With some help from [lunaryorn](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/users/227/lunaryorn) on [reddit](http://www.reddit.com/r/emacs/comments/2pavya/how_to_properly_defalias_lambda/cmvg73r), I guess I have been able to understand why you are observing the "wierd" behaviour.

The problem is that you are quoting the expression

```
'("foo" . (λ () (message "bar")))
```

Which is equivalent to the form

```
(cons "foo" '(λ () (message "bar")))
```

Now when emacs opens a file with extension "foo", it does something like the following

```
(funcall '(λ () (message "bar")))
```

Notice the extra quote, before `(λ`, this obviously is not valid function and you get the error `Invalid function: ...`
But then why does `("foo" . (lambda () (message "bar")))` work, this is explained by lunaryorn's observation

> A “lambda list”, i.e. a list whose car is lambda, is a valid function, too

So `'(lambda () (message "bar"))` is a valid function, this can be verified by the following code

```
(functionp (lambda () "hello"))  => t
(functionp (λ () "hello"))       => t
(functionp '(lambda () "hello")) => t
(functionp '(λ () "hello"))      => nil
```

So the solution would be to simply not quote the expression use the following instead

```
(add-to-list 'auto-mode-alist (cons "foo" (λ () (bar))))
```

Comment: Thanks for the thorough explanation!  Everything's working fine now :)

Answer (score 3):

It looks like the problem is not with the `defalias`, but rather where and how you're calling `λ`.  `funcall` takes, as its arguments, a function and that function's arguments, so your `funcall` example works just fine.

Both [`org-add-link-type`](http://orgmode.org/manual/Adding-hyperlink-types.html) and the [`auto-mode-alist`](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/AutoModeAlist), however, expect symbols that contain the relevant functions.  Hence, building off of your examples, the following should work:

```
(defun a-silly-fnx (s)
  (message s))
(defalias #'my-link-alias #'a-silly-fnx)
(org-add-link-type "foo" #'my-link-alias)

(defun a-tester-fnx ()
  (message "Testing!")
  (sit-for 2))
(defalias #'my-alist-alias #'a-tester-fnx)
(add-to-list 'auto-mode-alist '("foo" . my-alist-alias))
```

If you're mostly looking to have `λ` show up in your buffer, consider trying out [`prettify-symbols-mode`](http://ergoemacs.org/emacs/emacs_pretty_lambda.html), which will display `lambda` as `λ` without changing th buffer's text.

Comment: The weird thing is that everything works fine when I use `lambda` directly.

Comment: @rtrn: ah, good point.  I'm guessing it's because the `lambda` macro returns a self-quoted `lambda` special form which the alias isn't picking up, but there might be more black magic here.  Summon @Malabarba.